# how do i edit this transparent png keeping the same font

Tags: image-manipulation

i want to change the wording, and leave everything as it is....

http://i42.tinypic.com/27wyyo.png

what software do i use ?

Answer (score 1):

An image such as a PNG is "flattened" and doesn't offer a way to edit text on it. You will basically need image-editing software such as Adobe Photoshop, but even then it would be a matter of knowing the typeface used and re-creating the image in the first place. Your best bet may be to contact the author or creator of the image and find out if you can get a document that hasn't already been rendered as a flat image.

Answer (score 0):

While it will not work well for the image you supplied, I find the following web site invaluable in determining which font is used in graphics:

http://www.WhatTheFont.com

As for your question... You'll probably just have to create the picture from scratch (using your favorite graphics editor, mine is Paint.NET) after you discover the font used.

Besides the site above, you could check http://www.dafont.com to see if the font is a free one that you can download.

Comment: Looks like Helvetica and Century Gothic Oblique to me.

Comment: There's also identifont.com which is sometimes helpful.